# FB intergration with xcode HACK change screen (remove)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I implimented the FB post to my app so the users can post there high scores on fb to share with there friends,

but since this i now have 2 flick screen that come up with what liike like a blue book and says hack in them ( i know this is harmless but to the users they may not see it this way) how can i remove this.

i have uploaded a 8 second vid showing this.

[VID SHOWING HACK](http://youtu.be/9_I3NAtoSTI)

Comment: Did you accidentally copy-pasta some things from the hackbook demo that you shouldn't have?

Comment: i just copy and pasted the bit off the developers.facebook.com thing

Comment: Yer 3.2.6 why is that an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that somewhere along the way, you set your Default.png. Try deleting that file, and it should go away.

Comment: Sorted just added a new default.png image and it seems to overwrite the offending image (i know its probably not the best practice but it works)